# Super user on Windows

Tags: windows, performance, uninstall

I remember someone showing me a software on windows. It had super user privileges and could manage (almost) everything like uninstalling programs not shown in Programs and Features. Does anyone have a clue on what the program is?

My computer is giving me headaches in it's performance and I need to fix it up a bit.

Thank you.

Note: If it's not a proper question please tell me.

Comment: Are you talking about the `Administrator` account? If so, you don't need software for that. You also need to specify what version of Windows you're using.

Comment: @happy_soil A more direct equivalent to the *nix `root` is the `SYSTEM` account in Windows, but there are very few circumstances where it might actually be useful. `Administrator` (user and group) is enough in most cases.

Comment: If your computer is slow and you're an "Administrator" (you can see this under your name in User Accounts in Control Panel) you have all the rights you need to fix the performance of your computer. (Beginning with installing and running [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) and removing all the spyware-apps from your "Programs and Features" in Control Panel) Programs not shown in "Programs and Features" don't have an official uninstall (like spyware/malware) and need to be removed differently (how is dependent on that software).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/). It sounds like this is your program.

It has many features to improve the speed of your computer and to remove unimportant things:

> **Browser-cleaning**
>
> - Deleting of Temporary files, history, cookies, super cookies, Autocomplete form history, index.dat files in browsers.
>
> **Windows**
>
> - Recycle Bin, Recent Documents, Temporary files, Log files, Clipboard, DNS Cache, Error Reporting, Memory Dumps, Jump Lists.
>     Registry
>
> **Registry Cleaner**
>
> - Advanced features to remove unused and old entries, including File Extensions, ActiveX Controls, ClassIDs, ProgIDs, Uninstallers, Shared
>     DLLs, Fonts, Help Files, Application Paths, Icons, Invalid Shortcuts
>     and more... Applications
>
> **Third-party applications**
>
> - Removes temp files and recent file lists (MRUs) from many apps including Windows Media Player, eMule, Google Toolbar, Microsoft
>     Office, Nero, Adobe Acrobat, WinRAR, WinAce, WinZip and many more...

[Source](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/features)

I would recommend you, to have a look at the applications at the startup-items. With ccleaner you can easily remove them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's not what I was looking for but I've completely forgotten about the functions in CCleaner other than "cleaning". I'll give them a try.

Comment: Finally got rid of a lot of useless cra... I mean stuff. I still need to increase performance but I can't afford to re-install windows.

Comment: Also look in `taskmanager` what processes are running (including "Show processes from all users") and see if there are some you don't need. (I know the names are weird but you can learn a lot there, Google them, or use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which includes a search for processes with a right-click) You can stop some programs from running after a restart by disabling them in `msconfig`. I've never re-installed an OS on my system (other than test-configs in Virtual Machines). I always keep it clean and running smooth.